# A Rhymeless Riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I am your new friend, ornately adorned,
>   With a prime seat at the table and manners to match.
>
> I was summoned from the vault for destruction,
>   And in purity, purify.
>
> But should I join with another, don't let it rain on your parade -
>   Smile big for the camera!

Who am I?

Comment: Sounds chemical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are:

> Silver (Ag)

Because:

> This element sits on the 47th place in the table of elements, which is a prime number. Silver is clearly our "friend", because many people carry ornamental accesories made of it (jewellery). **"Summoned from the vault for destruction and in purity, purify"** maybe means when Silver was used as a material to produce bullets, and Silver ions is used nowadays to purify water. When you say **"should I join with with another, don't let rain on your parade"** maybe you could be talking about the Copper-Silver ionization, used as a water disinfection agent. Finally, **"smile big for the camera"** might be giving us a clue of the uses of Silver in photography: films, photo printing papers and batteries.

Hope it's not too far!

**Full solution**

I am your new friend, ornately adorned,

> There's [a song](http://www.scoutsongs.com/lyrics/makenewfriends.html) which goes "Make new friends, but keep the old. / One is silver, the other is gold." "Ornately adorned" refers to fancy jewelry and accessories.

With a prime seat at the table and manners to match.

> Number 47 (a prime) in the periodic table of elements. Fancy place settings have lots of silverware, and knowing which fork to use is important etiquette.

I was summoned from the vault for destruction,

> [History trivia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver#World_War_II), silver was borrowed from the U.S. Treasury for use in WWII weaponry, including the Manhattan Project.

And in purity, purify.

> Silver nanoparticles are used to purify water.

But should I join with another, don't let it rain on your parade -

> These lines are both about silver alloys. Silver iodide is used to [seed clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) to produce or attempt to redirect rainfall.

Smile big for the camera!

> Silver mercury alloy is used to fill cavities, and film uses silver nitrate or silver halides.

And the title: "A Rhymeless Riddle"

> "Silver" does not have any perfect rhymes in English

Comment: Correct answer :D Not what I was hinting at with the vault and rain clues though (forgot about the bullets, actually!), and there's still a few that I hoped someone would pick up on. I'm pretty new here, should I wait to accept or just add the rest of the answers?

Comment: Thanks! If this is the answer you had in mind, you can go ahead and accept it - if some details are missing, you can just edit my post to make it fit your ideas! Upvoting it is also helpful. Oh, and great puzzle by the way!!

Comment: Thanks :) I added the rest of the answers I was thinking of, hope that's ok. Of course, feel free to edit it how you like!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe-

> hydrogen?

With a prime seat at the table and manners to match.

> prime number in the table of elements?

I was summoned from the vault for destruction,
And in purity, purify.

> reactive and can seperate compounds when in its pure form?

But should I join with another, don't let it rain on your parade -

> combines with oxygen to make water/rain.

Smile big for the camera!

> used in ye-olde photography maybe?

My subject knowledge is shockingly bad...

Comment: You're definitely thinking along the right tracks, but this isn't quite it - there's also a few clues you missed that don't work with this answer. (To be fair, I did do a little research to fill out the lines, but it's not very obscure and/or is easy to find, once you know what you're looking for..)

Answer (score 0):

I am too new to comment, but the correct answer did not note that

> silver iodide is used for cloud seeding

and regarding destruction:

> Ancient Greeks used silver to 'destroy' bacterial infection

Comment: Just added to that answer, you are spot on with the first! Nice interpretation on the second too, I am learning all sorts of new things through this :)